# AWS CodeBuild. Could not load SDK Resolver

Tags: aws-codebuild

I've got a CodeBuild project that builds on an AWS Windows container (not a custom container), and I've started getting the following error when the app tries to build. Nothing has changed in my setup. It sounds like an issue with the build container, which as far as I know I don't have access to, and can't really do anything about? Has anyone come across this error before?

> Error MSB4247: Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists,
>   but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found. Manifest
>   file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'.
>   SDK resolver path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll

Comment: I have the same issue.